# Generalising tensor products of vectors to tensor products of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose that $x\in\mathbb R^p$ and $y\in\mathbb R^q$. Then the tensor product of $x$ and $y$ is defined as $x\otimes y=xy'\in\mathbb R^{p\times q}$ which can be viewed as an operator (a matrix in this case) that maps the elements of $\mathbb R^q$ to $\mathbb R^p$ and we have that $y'z\cdot x$ which means that $x$ is scaled by $y'z$.

Now suppose we have two matrices $X\in\mathbb R^{p\times q}$ and $Y\in\mathbb R^{r\times s}$. Following the lines of the vector case, the tensor product $X\otimes Y$ is an operator that maps $\mathbb R^{r\times s}$ to $\mathbb R^{p\times q}$ but how does this operator look like? Do we have something similar to $\langle Y,Z\rangle X$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is some inner product on $\mathbb R^{r\times s}$? Would this be the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)? Is there an expression of $X\otimes Y$ similar to $xy'$ in the vector case?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This operator already exists : it is the **Kronecker product** of the 2 matrices.

Comment: @JeanMarie I thought that it is not the same thing: we have the outer product of two vectors which is the tensor product and then we have the Kronecker product of two vectors. The article about the outer product on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) starts by saying that the outer product contrasts with the Kronecker product. If $X\in\mathbb R^{p\times q}$ and $Y\in\mathbb R^{r\times s}$, then the Kronecker product is a matrix in $\mathbb R^{pr\times qs}$. How does this matrix map the elements of $\mathbb R^{r\times s}$ to $\mathbb R^{p\times q}$?

Comment: I find this Wikipedia article more confusing than not when it says that there is a contrast between $\otimes_{Kron}$ and $\otimes_{outer}\,.$ This is just a trivial vectorization of a matrix. As elements of the vector space $U\otimes V$ they are the same. It does not matter how we arrange a bunch of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to generalize the outer product operation in this way is via the [product of tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Tensor_product). For a tensor of type $(1,0)$ (corresponding to a "column-vector" $x \in \Bbb R^p$) and a tensor $y$ of type $(0,1)$ (corresponding to a "row vector" $y \in \Bbb R^q$), the tensor product of $x$ and $y$ is the operator $x \otimes y = x_iy^j$. Alternatively, if we want to think of $y$ as being a column vector, then the outer product is really $x \otimes (y')$; that is, we can transpose $y$ to change its type in order for the tensor product to work as expected. To apply this tensor to a vector $z \in \Bbb R^q$ (in particular a "column-vector", a tensor with the same size but opposite type of $y$), we compute the product
$$
(x \otimes y)z = x_iy^jz_j = (y^jz_j) \cdot x,
$$
where per the Einstein summation convention, $y^jz_j$ is shorthand for the sum $\sum_{j=1}^q y^j z_j$. Note that we have taken the product of two tensors of opposite "type".

When you say that you want $X \otimes Y$ to work as a linear map from $\Bbb R^{p\times q}$ to $\Bbb R^{r \times s}$, there's some ambiguity as to whether we're interpreting the elements of $\Bbb R^{p\times q}$ as $(2,0),(1,1),$ or $(0,2)$ tensors. A $(1,1)$ tensor is a linear map, a $(0,2)$ tensor is a bilinear form, and a $(2,0)$ tensor has no common interpretation. I'll suppose that we're thinking of $X$ as a linear map, which is to say a $(1,1)$ tensor. In other words, we identify elements of $\Bbb R^{p\times q}$ with multilinear maps $\tilde X:(\Bbb R^p)^* \times \Bbb R^q \to \Bbb R$.

For two matrices $X\in\mathbb R^{p\times q}$ and $Y$, if the tensor $X \otimes Y$ is to be interpreted as a map from $\Bbb R^{r \times s}$ to $\Bbb R^{p \times q}$, we actually need $Y$ to be a tensor of the opposite type of $\Bbb R^{r \times s}$. That is, instead of $Y$ being a multilinear map $(\Bbb R^r)^* \times (\Bbb R^s) \to \Bbb R$, we need it to be a map $(\Bbb R^s)^* \times (\Bbb R^r) \to \Bbb R$, which is to say an $s \times r$ matrix. Alternatively, if we really want to think of $Y$ as being $r \times s$, we can transpose it to change its type in order for the tensor product to work as expected.

Taking $Y$ to be an $s \times r$ matrix, we can apply $X \otimes Y$ as in the following product:
$$
(X \otimes Y)Z = X^i_j  = (Y^k_\ell Z^\ell_k) X^i_j.
$$
In other words, $(X \otimes Y)Z = \operatorname{trace}(YZ)X$. Alternatively, if we take $Y$ to be $r \times s$ and transpose it for the tensor product, then this becomes
$$
(X \otimes (Y'))Z = X^i_j  = ((Y')^k_\ell Z^\ell_k) X^i_j = \operatorname{trace}(Y'Z)X = \langle Y,Z \rangle X,
$$
where $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ is the Frobenius inner product, as you suggested.